# Terminate a long running process

Tags: c, database, oracle, solaris

Hi I am using C on Solaris. I have a process which connects to a database. I need to determine if the same process is running the same query for a long time (say 15 seconds) then I need to disconnect and re establish the database connections.

> I know I can check for the same
>   processes with the process id's. But I
>   am more concerned about in knowing how
>   to determine if a same process is
>   running the same query?

Any help is deeply appreciable.

Comment: What database are you using? Some DB engines can give you access to a list of sessions via SQL (like Oracle's view V$SESSION) which can be interrogated.

Answer (score 1):

if you start your queries straight from your client, you can check `v$session.last_call_et`. This column shows how many seconds ago the last server call started for this session. A server call in this case is the execute query. This won't work is your client starts a block of pl/sql and happens to start the querie[s] from there. In that case last_call_et will point to the start of the pl/sql block, since that was the last thing started by your session.
This could be the easiest.

Does it help?

Ronald - http://ronr.blogspot.com

Comment: In my case, there can be multiple client connecting to the database. So lets say for clients C1 and C2, the last call to the database can be made by C2 but I am intrested in knowing for how much time a same query is executed by C1.

Comment: If your C1 session is still executing your query, you can see how long it is running by checking the last_call_et column for that C1 session in v$session. This assumes that the query is executed directly by the client, not using a block of pl/sql or a procedure, because in that case last_call_et only shows the age expressed in seconds of the run of that last call.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to determine if the same process is running the same query for a long time (say 15 seconds) then I need to disconnect and re establish the database connections."

Not sure what problem you are addressing.

If you drop the connection, then the database session may persist for some time. Potentially still holding locks too.

Also, if a PL/SQL block is looping and running 1000 queries each taking a tenth of a second, should that be counted as 1 statement for your abort logic ?

You can look at V$SESSION and the SQL_ID or SQL_HASH_VALUE. Then check again after fifteen seconds and see if it has changed. You can also look at v$sessstat / v$statname for things like "execute count" or "user calls" to determine whether it is the same SQL running for a long time or multiple SQL calls.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is that you fix the root cause instead of treating the symptoms.

Comment: In my case you are never sure about which query is taking the long time. So the Root Cause is unknown and needs to be find out by calculating the processing time of indivdual queries.